# Restore SQL Server 2005 database without overwriting DB users

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, database-restore

I have a database that I constantly need to restore.

Every time I do so, all the users that have access to DB are deleted and I have to manually add them again.

Is there any way that I can restore the DB but the users remain intact or any script that I run before/after the restore so that I don't have to manually add all the users again?

Comment: What are you using. Mysql, mssql, oracel ?

Comment: You should script your users and run the script after every restore. If those users aren't in the backup, and you restore over top of it, there's no way to say "completely overwrite this database *except* for the users..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the restore, you can script the users as they currently exist. In object explorer, expand the database, expand security, highlight the users node and click f8 (object explorer details). In object explorer details, select the users you want to keep, right click and script as create to new window, clipboard etc.

Now run the restore, and when the restore is complete, run the script from above. If this is all happening on the same server, should work just fine as I described. If these are different servers, you may want to look into synchronizing server-level logins first.

Answer (score 2):

Before you restore the database, use this script to script the logins and passwords: [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992)
Then, after you restore the database, execute the created script to re-create the logins